# angles in complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

There are two points $z_1$ and $z_2$ in the complex plane. What is the angle that the line segment $z_1 z_2$ subtends at the origin?

I want to find this angle in terms of $z_1,z_2$ and $|z_1−z_2|$ and if required, some other angle of the triangle formed but I need to avoid $|z_1|$ and $|z_2|$. Is this possible?

Comment: i want to find this angle in terms of $z_1, z_2 $ and $|z_1-z_2|$ and if required , some other angle of the triangle formed but i need to avoid $|z_1|$and $|z_2|$. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't put a modification of your problem in a comment (which will get lost).  Put it in your question itself.

Comment: Thanks David. did that.

Answer (score 0):

If $z_1 = a_1 e^{i \theta_1}$ and $z_2 = a_2 e^{i \theta_2}$, then $z_1 z_2 = a_1 a_2 e^{i (\theta_1 + \theta_2)}$ and the angle is of course $\theta_1 + \theta_2$.  Of course you don't need to use $a_1$ and $a_2$ if you have $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.

$$\theta_{12} = \arg (z_1 z_2) = \arg z_1 + \arg z_2$$

I think that is about as basic an answer as is mathematically possible.

Comment: yes but i need to avoid $a_1$ and $a_2$. If required i can use some other angles of the triangle

Answer (score 0):

By définition: $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg{z_1}+\arg{z_2}={(\overrightarrow{u},\overrightarrow{M_2M_1})}$ where $\overrightarrow{u}$ represent the unit vector of x-axis and $M_i$ the point of affix $z_i$ in the complex plane.

Comment: What is an "image of the complex $z_i$ within the complex plane"?

Comment: More precisely $M_i$ is the point of affix $z_i$